# Delphi drag and drop an image from canvas to a PaintBox

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

My intention is to have a PaintBox and several small images on a side. Then, I want to be able to drag each of the images inside the paintBox and arrange them there, so that later I can save the PaintBox with the resulting arrangement of images.
Is it possible? And how?

So far I can drag/drop controls (TControl) around a form, but since that is not what I need, I have difficulties with TImage and TPaintBox. (Meaning that the same code does not apply)

Is there a better way? I am trying to see if I can make a simple Paint app.
Does anyone have some code that would help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a `TImage` inside of a `TPaintBox`.  You have to draw everything inside of the `TPaintBox.OnPaint` event.  Create a separate list of non-`TImage` images that you draw when needed.

You need to use the `OnMouse...` events to know where the user is dragging within the PaintBox, using `Invalidate()` to trigger repaints so you can redraw the image that is being dragged.  In `OnMouseDown`, set a flag that dragging is active, and save the provided mouse coordinates and info about which image is being clicked on.  In `OnMouseUp`, clear the flag.  In `OnMouseMove`, if the drag flag is enabled, save the current mouse coordinates and call `Invalidate()`. In `OnPaint`, draw the image at the saved coordinates.

The alternative is to switch to `TPanel` or `TScrollBox`, and put `TImage` controls inside of it, then you can drag them around like any other control.